# ArgumentError - Wrong number of arguments when calling .all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to RoR and although I have done quite an extensive amount of searching on StackOverflow and Google, I can't seem to solve this problem.

In my controller, I have the following code to initialize the @coupon_categories instance variable, and continuously get this error in my index method:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

This is my CouponCategoryController file:

```
class CouponCategoryController < ApplicationController

   # Implemented when user input taken
   def index
     @coupon_categories = CouponCategory.all
   end

   def new
     @coupon_category = CouponCategory.new(params[:coupon_category])
   end
```

coupon_category.rb:

```
class CouponCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :coupons, :dependent => destroy # destroys coupons dependent on coupon_category  

end
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Edit: Here is my view file, along with the full error messages.
index.html.erb:

```
<h1> Create A Coupon Category! </h1>

<%= form_for :coupon_category do |f| %>
 Category Name: <%= f.text_field "name" %><br />
 Category expiration date (YYYY-MM-DD): <%= f.text_field "date_expired" %><br />
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => 'coupon/index' %>
```

Full error message:

```
ArgumentError in CouponCategoryController#index

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

app/models/coupon_category.rb:2:in `<class:CouponCategory>'
app/models/coupon_category.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/coupon_category_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you post your full stacktrace? (Everything below the `wrong number of arguments` error including line numbers)

Comment: As dylan hints, the problem is almost certainly not in your index method - the code looks fine.  Likely it is something in the view, which you are not showing us

Comment: Thank you both for your help - I've updated the original post to include the view file and the application error trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be

```
has_many :coupons, :dependent => destroy
```

The `destroy` should be a symbol, `:destroy`.

```
has_many :coupons, :dependent => :destroy
```